# Shared excel file that will email the user’s once the file is saved, not changed

Tags: excel

I’m trying to set up a shared file that will email the user’s once the file is saved, not changed.

The `code` I’m using is :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nConfirmation As Integer
    Dim objNewWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objNewWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim objOutlookApp As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    nConfirmation = MsgBox("Do you want to send an email notification about the sheet updating now?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Mail Sheet Updates")
    If nConfirmation = vbYes Then
       ActiveWorkbook.Save

       On Error Resume Next
       Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
       Set objMail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

             With objMail
           .To = "jasonc@jamesfrizelles.com.au"
           .Subject = "Email Notifying Sheet Updates"
           .Body = "Hi," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "The worksheet " & Chr(34) & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & Chr(34) & " in this Excel workbook attachment is updated."
           .Send
      End With
    End If
End Sub
```

If I change the Change to Save the code won’t work at all.

Any input ?

Regards

Jason Coram
Service Manager

Comment: In the ThisWorkbook code sheet there is a Workbook_BeforeSave.

Comment: Probably better to separate your email routine to a public sub in a module and just call it from Workbook_BeforeSave. Another idea, send them an SMS text msg to their phone.

Comment: If I change the to the above it become an error and goes to red.

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave.(ByVal Target As Range)

Comment: You have put it in the worksheet's private code sheet. Open the Project Explorer (ctrl+R) if it is not open and double-click ThisWorkbook to open the ThisWorkbook code sheet.

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Comment: The code now looks like this

Comment: Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeSave(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nConfirmation As Integer
    Dim objNewWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objNewWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim objOutlookApp As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
 nConfirmation = MsgBox("Do you want to send an email notification about the sheet updating now?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Mail Sheet Updates")
 
    If nConfirmation = vbYes Then
       ActiveWorkbook.Save

Comment: but still wont work

Comment: You cannot just change structured event handlers like Worksheet_Change or Workbook_BeforeSave. Save your code to notepad or somewhere and use he right dropdown on the thisworkbook code sheet to select beforesave. This will create a Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean) . Work with that.

Comment: please [edit] your question to put in your code. It's obviously unreadable in a comment.

Comment: My version of Excel doesn't have that option in the drop down box, however I was able to use the right click function.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean).

Comment: next question is on how to add multiple email address in the main file.

Comment: Why not just have a group in the email program - that will send to as many as you wish...